# SQL IF NOT EXISTS INSERT Else Update, based on column ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My goal is to get SQL to check if the row exists, if it does update, if not insert.

`FTP_num`  is the name of the first column. The SQL Statement is

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ftp_num from Distributor WHERE fpt_num = FTP_num)" 
" insert FTP_Info set IP=@IP, Port=@Port, UN=@UN, PW=@PW, Folder=@Folder where FTP_num = @ftp_num" +
" else" +
" update FTP_Info set IP=@IP, Port=@Port, UN=@UN, PW=@PW, Folder=@Folder where FTP_num = @ftp_num", con))
```

I don't have much SQL experience, any help is appreciated.

```
Line 120:
Line 121:                con.Open();
Line 122:                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 123:                con.Close();
Line 124:            }
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: based on the c# code using SqlCommand I guessed Sql server

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. SQL Server 2014

Comment: You're checking the `Distributor` table, but `INSERT/UPDATE` is against `FTP_Info`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Tom H Absolutely not. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert syntax is wrong.
It should be something like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1from Distributor WHERE fpt_num = @FTP_num)" +
                        " insert into FTP_Info (IP, Port, UN, PW, Folder, FTP_num) VALUES(@IP, @Port, @UN, @PW, @Folder @ftp_num)" +
                        " else" +
                        " update FTP_Info set IP=@IP, Port=@Port, UN=@UN, PW=@PW, Folder=@Folder where FTP_num = @ftp_num", con))
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the merge statement: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx for SQL Server, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm for Oracle

Comment: Please consider adding some code sample to your answer. right now it's not much better then a simple search results.

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested, MERGE statement is very appropriate here, since it may perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in an atomic instruction:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"
    MERGE Distributor AS T
    USING ( VALUES(@IP, @Port, @UN, @PW, @Folder, @FTP_Num) AS S
        (IP, Port, UN, PW, Folder, FTP_num)
    ON S.FTP_num = T.FTP_num
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES (S.IP, S.Port, S.UN, S.PW, S.Folder, S.FTP_num);
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET IP=@IP, Port=@Port, UN=@UN, PW=@PW, Folder=@Folder",
con);
```

My advice is to play with MERGE statement directly in `SSMS` and the port the code `.NET`, as it is more productive to spot the errors (it's a complex and quite ugly, yet powerful statement).

In your case, the source is plain data from the context, that is why the source (`S`) is formed from `VALUES`, not a `table` or a `view`.

More useful tips about MERGE statement can be found [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/merge-statement-tips).

Comment: I would suggest that better than trying to port the `MERGE` statement into .NET code would be to just wrap it in a stored procedure and save the headache of string manipulation, etc.

Comment: @TomH - Yes, it is a good advice. A good alternative is to use Entity Framework and get rid of manually writing simple queries :). In this case, I think it would generate a `SELECT TOP 1...` followed by `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, so the performance would very close to that of a MERGE.